# MySQL duplicates with CONCAT error 1548 - Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: mysql, duplicates, concatenation

i have this query witch concatenates firstname with last name and then find the duplicates:

```
SELECT import.*, import.CONCAT(nume,' ',prenume) full2 
FROM import 
INNER JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(nume,' ',prenume) full,COUNT(*) 
            FROM import 
            WHERE users_id=1 
            GROUP BY full 
            HAVING COUNT(*)>1) as t2 ON import.full2 = t2.full 
WHERE users_id=1
```

i think the sql syntax is correct but i get the error: 1548 - Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted

is there any problem with the 5.1.59 mysql version?

Answer (score 0):

Do that

```
CONCAT(import.nume,' ',import.prenume) full2
```

instead of

```
import.CONCAT(nume,' ',prenume) full2
```

### Update

Try that:

```
SELECT t1.*, CONCAT(t1.nume,' ',t1.prenume) full2 
FROM import t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(i2.nume,' ',i2.prenume) `full`, COUNT(*) 
        FROM import i2
        WHERE i2.users_id=1 
        GROUP BY `full`
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1) as t2 ON full2 = t2.`full` 
WHERE users_id=1
```

Comment: i get Unknown column 'import.full2' in 'on clause' without the import.

Comment: change `import.full2` in on clause to `full2`

Comment: i did that but still unknown column

Comment: Unknown column 't1.full2' in 'on clause'

Comment: Ah. My bad. Would you try leaving the `t1.` before the `full`: `ON full2 = t2.full`. If that doesn't work. then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT import.*, import.CONCAT(nume,' ',prenume) full2
```

to

```
SELECT import.*, CONCAT(import.nume,' ',import.prenume) as full2
```

Note the change to the `CONCAT` statement and the `as` addition for using column aliases

as you are using a single table you could remove the `import.` from the column list ... alternatively you could use a table alias

```
SELECT i.*, CONCAT(i.nume,' ',i.prenume) as full2 
FROM import i
WHERE i.user_id = 1
```

as an example.

[See the MySQL docs here on using the AS alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id742747)

Answer (score 0):

Examines all tables in all databases for incompatibilities with the current version of MySQL Server:

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html